# Converting $\frac{x^2}{4}+y^2\leq1$ to parametric form

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections

I have $\dfrac{x^2}{4}+y^2\leq1$ to be converted to parametric equation.

I have tried,

$x^2+4y^2\leq4$

$x^2\leq4(1-y^2)$

$x^2\leq4(1-y)(1+y)$

I am doubting for my next step since this is an inequality. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Do you know what parametric equations are?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Use the fact that $\cos^2(t) + \sin^2(t) = 1$ and set

$$ \begin{aligned}
  x^2/4 & = \cos^2(t) \\
  y^2 & = \sin^2(t)
\end{aligned}$$

Solve the above for $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ and prove that it solves the equation of the ellipse for *all values of $t$*.

Comment: There's trouble with $\pm$ signs. It's better to define $x$ and $y$ directly in terms of $t$. Also, the inequality describes the ellipse's interior, not only its boundary.

Comment: I think we want something like $x=2u\cos t,\;y=u\sin t$, so the inequality becomes $u^2\leq1$.

Comment: Sorry, yes. I still don't see the trouble with signs.

Comment: The trouble is that the solution to $y^2=\sin^2 t$ is not unique; it could be $y=\sin t$ or $y=-\sin t$.

Comment: @mr_e_man - it is not a problem because both solutions parametrize the curve. Parametrization does not have a unique solution.